saving a JS object to a zip archive and extracting arbitrary keys
How can I create a zip archive from an object, an archive to which I can add more keys or extract arbitrary keys without unzipping the entire archive to disk first?
To be clear, I know how I can zip up a variable to a zip archive. But, how do I add to that archive and then extract only one key from the archive? Something like so (pseudocode)
addToArchive('archive.zip', {able: 'dsaf 2342 sdf'});
addToArchive('archive.zip', {abner: 'hsf= 424 asfs'});
addToArchive('archive.zip', {about: 'sds 322dfs df 23'});

// some time later
console.log(extractFromArchive('archive.zip', 'abner'))
// 'hsf= 424 asfs'

Background
I am writing a program that creates and stores 10s (maybe 100s) of 1000s of tiny files like so (I store them in a multilevel hierarchy of folders to ensure no one folder has too many files)
├── a
│   ├── ab
│   │   ├── abl
│   │   │   └── able.txt
│   │   ├── abn
│   │   │   └── abner.txt
│   │   ├── abo
│   │   │   ├── about.txt
│   │   │   └── above.txt
│   │   └── abr
│   │       └── abrasive.txt

Once the files are stored, I can open any file very fast just by knowing its name. For example, 'abrasive' is available at ./a/ab/abr/abrasive.txt.
But creating and storing these files is very inefficient. So, I thought I could zip them up and then extract a specific file from the zip archive using something like node-stream-zip or adm-zip. But, to create the zip archive, I need to store these files first anyway, which defeats the purpose.

"Is there a way to create a zip archive from an object like below" Yes, of course. What's the actual question here?

How? I have clarified the text in the OP
